# Concourse Worker Failure on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: concourse

After configuring a standalone Concourse 2.4.0 per the [instructions](http://concourse.ci/binaries.html), everything seems to be up and running. However, when trying to run the ["hello world" example](http://concourse.ci/hello-world.html), I can see the following error in the Concourse UI:

`runc create: exit status 1: rootfs ("/volumes/live/a72f9a0d-3506-489b-5b9b-168744b892c1/volume") does not exist`

"web" start command:

`./concourse web \
  --basic-auth-username admin \
  --basic-auth-password admin \
  --session-signing-key session_signing_key \
  --tsa-host-key host_key \
  --tsa-authorized-keys authorized_worker_keys \
  --external-url http://myconcoursedomain:8080 \
  --postgres-data-source postgres://user:pass@mydbserver/concourse`

"worker" start command:

`./concourse worker \
  --work-dir worker \
  --tsa-host 127.0.0.1 \
  --tsa-public-key host_key.pub \
  --tsa-worker-private-key worker_key`

I'm wondering if the problem occurs since the "missing" directory is created in the directory specified in the "start worker" command, instead of at the actual root directory:

`~/concourse# ls -la worker
total 145740
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root        4096 Nov 15 23:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root        4096 Nov 15 23:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root        4096 Nov 15 23:07 2.4.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root        4096 Nov 15 23:09 depot
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root          24 Nov 15 23:07 volumes
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42142052352 Nov 15 23:15 volumes.img`

Concourse is installed on Ubuntu 14.04:

`uname -r
4.4.0-47-generic
uname -a
Linux ubuntu-2gb-nyc3-01 4.4.0-47-generic #68~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:42:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Tried creating a symlink to my worker/volumes directory at the root and now I get a different error: `runc create: exit status 1: /volumes/live/eacdf0a1-6d6f-4051-6a85-d993b621764c/volume is not an absolute path or is a symlink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons that I still do not understand, it appears that if you specify the `--work-dir` value to be `/opt/concourse/worker`, then the worker will work with this kernel version without issue.

I was using a relative path to a worker directory within a dir in my user folder as my `--work-dir` value.